# How to login in website and click button and get the source code using python

Tags: python

How to login in website using python?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



url = 'http://example.com/login'
values = {'email': 'abc@email.com',
  'password': '123'}

r = requests.post(url, headers=HEADERS, data=values)
```

Here is my code to login. After login, it will go to home.html. I want to click the refer button and it will go to example.com/refer.html and I want to copy my unique code and print it in python.

My problem is how to click the refer button and copy the value of the input box.

Here is the input box in example.com/refer.html

```
<input type="text" value="m2m=1335519" id="myInput2">
```

I want to print the value of input box. The python should print m2m=1335519

I have a simple code to copy the value in input tag but this produce empty value "" because this is redirecting to home because this code dont login

```
url = 'example.com/refer.html'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
for link in soup.findAll(id='myInput2'):
    print(link.get('value'))
```

Answer (score 1):

The response from the login page should contain some value (probably a cookie, but could be something else) that identifies the login, and which needs to be passed with the request to the referral page.

So, your code needs to handle cookies.

Have a look at this gist, where I try to scrape my friends profiles for contact information (the code is old and probably doesn't work anymore with current facebook - I haven't tried this in a long time, also the original source is [here](https://gist.github.com/gelendir/718149)):

https://gist.github.com/kutschkem/7690411#file-infb-py-L83

```
CHandler = urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookielib.CookieJar())
browser = urllib2.build_opener(CHandler)
urllib2.install_opener(browser)

#Retrieve login form data and initialize the cookies
res = browser.open('https://www.facebook.com/login.php')

#Determine string encoding
content_type = res.info()['Content-Type'].split('; ')
encoding = 'utf-8'
if len(content_type) > 1 and content_type[1].startswith('charset'):
    encoding = content_type[1].split('=')[1]
html = bytes.decode( res.read(), encoding=encoding )
res.close()

#scrape form for hidden inputs, add email and password to values
form_scraper = FormScraper()
form_scraper.feed(html)
form_data = form_scraper.values
form_data.extend( [('email', user), ('pass', passw)] )
#HACK: urlencode doesn't like strings that aren't encoded with the 'encode' function.
#Using html.encode(encoding) doesn't help either. why ??
form_data = [ ( x.encode(encoding), y.encode(encoding) ) for x,y in form_data ]
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(form_data)

# Login
print ('Logging in to account ' + user)
res = browser.open('https://login.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1', str.encode(data))
rcode = res.code
print (rcode)
print (res.url)
if re.search('/login.php?login_attempt=1', res.url):
    print ('Login Failed')
    exit(2)
res.close()

# Get Emails and Phone Numbers
print ("Getting Info..\n")
for friend in friends['data']:
    print(friend)
    prof = 'http://facebook.com/' + str(friend['id'])
    res = browser.open(prof)
    # do stuff with the responds
```

The main point here is that an object from urllib is used which takes care of the cookie handling. The way you are doing it now, there is no connection between the login attempt and the reading of the referral page, they are just to requests. From the viewpoint of the page, this is two users making seperate requests. To connect the dots, you need cookie handling.

Answer (score 0):

first, create a soup var

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page ‘html.parser’)
```

then create another var to find the value with soup.find

```
val = soup.find('input', {'id': 'myInput2'}).get('value')
print(val)
```

Comment: how can i go to example.com/refer.html?

Comment: please explain your question in breif

Comment: that code produse blank because that is not login in the website